# UnhandledAlertException despite dismissing alerts in Selenium/Chrome

Tags: c#, selenium-chromedriver, unhandled-exception

I'm using Selenium with Chromedriver in C#:

```
<packages>
  <package id="Selenium.Chrome.WebDriver" version="2.42" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Selenium.WebDriver" version="3.14.0" targetFramework="net461" />
</packages>
```

When opening web pages containing alerts I always get an exception:

```
unexpected alert open: {Alert text : muh}
  (Session info: chrome=69.0.3497.100)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.42.591088 (7b2b2dca23cca0862f674758c9a3933e685c27d5),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)
```

Example Code:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {

            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.UnhandledPromptBehavior = UnhandledPromptBehavior.Dismiss;

            using (var browser = new ChromeDriver(options)) {
                browser.Navigate().GoToUrl(@"D:\downloads\test.html");
                Console.WriteLine(browser.PageSource); //Exception happens here
            }

            Console.WriteLine("done");
            Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Example HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script>
alert("muh");
document.write("<p>blah</p>");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

It looks like `options.UnhandledPromptBehavior = UnhandledPromptBehavior.Dismiss` just doesn't make any difference. What should I do to prevent this excpetion?

Answer (score 0):

Try to solve it with try/catch:

```
try
{
  Console.WriteLine(browser.PageSource); //Exception happens here
}
catch (UnhandledAlertException unhandledAlertException)
{
   // ignore exception or put the rest of the code
}
```

Comment: I need to access the `browser.PageSource`. It does not help to catch the exception when accessing it.